# Using threads in the right way

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm working on server written in python. When the client sends a cmd the server will call a function with unknown running time. So to avoid blocking I used threading. But when looking at the child process it seems that they're not terminating, causing a lot of memory usage.
EDIT : Here is the tree of the directory : http://pastebin.com/WZDxLquC

Following answers I found on stackoverflow I implemented a custom Thread class:

## sThreads.py :

```
import threading
 
 class Thread(threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, aFun, args = ()):
     super(Thread, self).__init__(None, aFun, None, args)
     self.stopped = threading.Event()
 
   def stop(self):
     self.stopped.set()
 
   def isStopped(self):
    return self.stopped.isSet()
```

Then here is the server's loop:

some where in mainServer.py:

```
def serve_forever(self,  aCustomClass, aSize = 1024):
    while True:
      self.conn, self.addr = self.sock.accept()
      msg = self.recvMSG(4096)
      if(msg):
        self.handShake(msg)
        print 'Accepted !'
        while True:
          msg = self.recvMSG(aSize)
          if(msg):
            t = sThreads.Thread(self.handle, (aCustomClass,))
            t.start()
            self.currentThreads.append(t)

            if(self.workers > 0):
              tt = sThreads.Thread(self.respond)
              tt.start()


            if(self.workers == 0 and len(self.currentThreads) > 0):
              for th in self.currentThreads:
                th.stop()
```

Using a custom Thread class will not solve the issue and it still does not stop the terminated threads!

EDIT : added the handle() and respond() methods :

```
  def handle(self, aClass):
    self.workers += 1
    self.queue.put(aClass._onRecieve(self.decodeStream()))

  def respond(self):
    while self.workers > 0:
      msgToSend, wantToSend = self.queue.get()
      self.workers -= 1
      if(wantToSend):
        print 'I want to send :', msgToSend
        continue #Send is not yet implemented !
```

Comment: `serve_forever()` has seven levels of nested loops and ifs. I have no idea what it's actually supposed to do? Is all the code in it really relevant to the problem you're seeing? The code the threads you spawn off run also isn't included. The threads should stop automatically once `handle()` and `respond()` are done.

Comment: Also, it seems to me like you're starting *multiple* threads for every client connection, which sounds like a recipe for disaster - what if they all read from / write to the client connection at the same time?

Comment: Apart from the good suggestions above, I have a minor one: I think this entire part can be replaced with just `else`: `if(self.workers == 0 and len(self.currentThreads) > 0)`

Comment: @millimoose: 1- when running test, handle() and respond() were really done but there the threads were not stopped automatically !

2- No threads are started for each message recieved not every client connection

Comment: @JohnZwinck : note that recvMsg() is a blocking function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that self.queue.get() was causing all the issue ...